# TinyMCE: disable automatic adding tags

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I use TinyMCE in my script to edit header and footer templates. But TinyMCE automatic add tags to close them, what I don't want. for example: the end of my header

```
</nav> <!--end menu--> <!--end header--></header>
```

TinyMCE makes it

```
</nav> <!--end menu--> <!--end header--></header></div></div>
```

How can I disable that? I already tried

```
verify_html : false,
verify_css_classes : true,
cleanup : false,
cleanup_on_startup : false,
```

Comment: I took out some `<br>`s that were in your question assuming you just wanted newlines on here. If that wasn't the case go ahead and add them back.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        verify_html : false,
        verify_css_classes : true,
        cleanup : false,
        cleanup_on_startup : false,
        ...
});
```