# TinyMCE autocloses HTML tags - How to disable?

Tags: xhtml, tinymce

In [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/), when I edit HTML code (using [code plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/)) and delete closing tags it will automatically add them right after clicking OK.

For example a piece of code like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Foo</th>
    </tr>
```

becomes

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I find this unwanted in my usecase but I cannot figure out how to turn it off.

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9674389/1429387) and tried these options with no result:

```
forced_root_block: false,
verify_html: false,
verify_css_classes: false,
cleanup: false,
cleanup_on_startup: false,
fix_list_elements: false,
valid_children: '+body[style],head[style]',
valid_elements: '*[*]',
```

My TinyMCE version is 4.3.11.

Comment: There is no setting to disable TinyMCE wanting to create valid well-formed HTML ... that is how the product was built.

Comment: What kind of usecase is it that requires outputting invalid HTML?

Comment: @MrLister break a page into pieces and edit in multiple editors

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE is an awesome addition to the community, with that being said it was meant for users that do not regularly code in HTML. If the HTML tags are not auto generated and one of your users did not specify the html on the page, the page would not look correct. This is why TinyMCE has an auto clean on start to clean up HTML code.

Anyway to disable the auto html you need to disable the  `verify_html : false,` on newer editions you might not be able to disable validation but you can define how TinyMCE will treat html tags. as some tags you will want to keep like the `<h1>`,`<h2>` ect.., here is a [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) and the link to the [forum post](http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=103637#p103637).

I hope this helps you

**EDIT:**

MAybe a code editor would suit you better. **[CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/doc/realworld.html)** CodeMirror is a JavaScript component that provides a code editor in the browser. When a mode is available for the language you are coding in, it will color your code, and optionally help with indentation.

Comment: 1. I've tried `verify_html: false`;
2. CodeMirror is not a WYSIWYG editor

Comment: I meant codeMirror for your personal use, not for the clients. But you can still edit the file to define what tags you want verify_html to use, like i said dont think you can use verify_html : false on the newer version.

Comment: I would understand not having the page tags or changing the page tags to div tags, but dont know why you would want to leave a table open. but either way you can accomplish this in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a single input, [Fullpage plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/fullpage/), and HTML comments `<!-- like this one -->` as dividers.

TinyMCE preserves HTML comments, but they are not visible in editor. Only in Code view.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons why you might want to disable the auto closing of tags. For me its because I have to copy paste a ton of text content then mark it up. So I get this...

```
<p>

</p>Airstream hitching is a much longer and more complicated...
```

when I type the opening p tag next to the word Airstream.

I have resorted to typing all the closing tags first. Telling people the 8million reasons why this is somehow good for them is just lame. Who cares why they want to disable this? We don't all need WP and everything else to protect our code from ourselves.

Comment: It removed my html. The closing p tag is added before the content and after two line returns now followed by the text.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow :) just learn to use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so your HTML is properly formatted and not removed.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I’m having trouble understanding your answer. My question is **"How to disable the autoclosing of tags in TinyMCE?"**, not "What's your reason to disable the autoclosing of tags in TinyMCE?".