# TinyMCE autocloses HTML tags - How to disable? 2

Tags: tinymce, xhtml

[Same question as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162298/tinymce-autocloses-html-tags-how-to-disable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have two tinymce Editors One of them for Header other for Footer(needs o be done for email template).
I want for example to have

`<div>abra` in Header editor. **After saving becomes `<div>abra</div>`**(closes the tag)

And

`cadabra</div>` in Footer editor. **After saving becomes `cadabra`**(removes tag)

so that at the end I could get `<div>abracadabra</div>`

How can i disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable TinyMCE from trying to create valid, well-formed HTML.  The engine that drives TinyMCE is designed to ensure that the content in any one editor is valid and well-formed and while you realize that the data across two editors is intended to be correct TinyMCE won't allow you to do this.  You could certainly post-process the data when extracting it from TinyMCE to get your desired end result.